# BinaryReader and Stream performance on WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

The question...

If you must have a BinaryReader opend to a file, is there a more performant way to do it than opening a Stream to a Resource?

```
 System.IO.Stream myFileStream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri @"/MyApp;component/sdb.data", UriKind.Relative)).Stream;
 BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(myFileStream);
```

All the rest...

I am using the [Sterling](http://sterling.codeplex.com/) Database (codeplex) for a WP7 app. The app is required to ship with a large db already inside the assembly. Currently, I am attempting a Restore() with Sterling to create a database from a file that holds a previously saved ( Backup() ). Currently, I am taking the backup file and setting it as a 'Resource' in the app, as shown above. The Sterling dtabase engine requires a BinaryReader to load the data via a Restore(). Currently, the restore just takes too long. I have a discussion started in the [Sterling Discussions](http://sterling.codeplex.com/discussions/257288), but posted here on Stack just to see if I could do better than a stream to a resource.

Comment: There's a missing parenthesis after new Uri but I can't edit because it says "Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post bla blah blah".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you are embedding your database as a resource - have you tried setting the Build Action property on the file to Content, and then loading it like this:

```
System.IO.Stream myFileStream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(@"/component/sdb.data", UriKind.Relative)).Stream;
```

Although I've not tried it myself, using Content over Resource apparently has performance implications for images, and I assume, for other binary files: http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/wp7-working-with-images-content-vs-resource-build-action

Comment: Actually, a test showed that in my case the emulator took 3:19 using build action of 'Content', and 2:08 using 'Resource'. Obviously, I am dealing with a large file.

Comment: It will likely be the same, but I'd be interested in hearing the difference on a real device

Comment: ha ha.. sure.. but that will have to wait till I have 20 minutes to spare :p

Comment: I have had to abandon using Sterling in the phone as the Restore to Isolated Storage is too slow (it takes minutes for a small database), so in the end I used Sterling to help generate a code file which loads all the objects in memory! I mean it explicitly instantiates the objects in code...  Performs great!